# When is the composition of multiple flows the identity?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I have some number of vector fields $a,b,\ldots,k$, and I denote flow along $a$ for time $t$ by $a_t$, etc.

When is it the case that for all points $x$, $a_tb_tc_t\ldots k_tx = x$?

In the special case where there are four vector fields and $c=-a, d=-b$ it is well-known that the condition is that their Lie derivative vanishes, i.e. $0 = [a,b] = \nabla_ab - \nabla_ba$ at every point. How does this condition generalize to arbitrarily many vector fields?

One idea I had is to write down the total flow, $f(x,t) = a_tb_tc_t\ldots k_tx$, and set its time derivatives to zero. I get that for the first derivative,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,0) = a + b + \ldots + k$$
which makes perfect sense. The second derivative is a bit unpleasant but assuming I carried out all of the chain rules correctly, I get
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}(x,0) = [a,b]+[a,c]+\ldots+[a,k]+[b,c]+\ldots+[b,k]+\ldots+[j,k]$$
which, at least, does have symmetry under cyclic permutation (since all of the terms involving $k$ cancel, and so can be negated) and gives the right answer for the special case of $a,b,-a,-b$.

1. Is the above formula correct? Is there a simpler formulation?
2. Is the formula sufficient? Or do I have to look at the higher derivatives of $t$ (computing the third derivative does not look at all pleasant...)

Comment: The condition $[a,b]=0$ gives $a_t b_t x = b_t a_t x$, not $a_t b_t x=x$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark There was a mistake in the question, I meant for the special case to be four vector fields, with $c=-a$ and $d=-b$. The case of two vector fields is trivial; since $a=-b$ also $[a,b]=0$.